# MongoDB doesn't reconnect when it hanged or crushed in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using nodejs and a mongoDB , and I'm having some connection issues.
below is my code:

```
let url='mongodb://xxx';
let mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
mongoClient.connect(url,(err, db)=>{
    routes(app, db);
    let server = http.Server(app);
    server.listen(port,(err)=>{})
})
```

sometime it seems crushed or hanged, so how to let it reconnect automatically?or is there exits a better solution?Mongodb version is 2.6.3

Comment: [Reliably reconnect to MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785036/reliably-reconnect-to-mongodb)

Comment: I see , thank you!