# How can I detect mongodb err and response immediatly while pooling?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is connection pooling code.

```
var express = require('express');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var app = express();

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;

// Initialize connection once
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_test", function(err, database) {
  if(err) throw err;

  db = database;

  // Start the application after the database connection is ready
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});

// Reuse database object in request handlers
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  db.collection("replicaset_mongo_client_collection").find({}, function(err, docs) {
    docs.each(function(err, doc) {
      if(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
      }
      else {
        res.end();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

My question is if the server started successfully but the connection to the MongoDB is lost (or shut down) during operation.

How do I catch this when requesting to my server?
not response like 'failed to reconnect after 30 attempts with interval 1000 ms'

## Solved

```
// Added global value to flag event
var MongoPool = true;

// Initialize connection once
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_test", function(err, database) {
  if(err) throw err;

  db = database;

  // Listen event
  db.on('close', function () {
   console.log('Conection closed');
   MongoPool = false;
  });

  // Start the application after the database connection is ready
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});

// Reuse database object in request handlers
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  if(MongoPool){
     // query
  } else {
     // response immediatly :)
  };
});
```

or you can modify MongoDB connection retry via below link
[Reliably reconnect to MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785036/reliably-reconnect-to-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using listeners for events like `close` or `error`

```
db.on('close', function () {
  console.log('Conection closed');
});

db.on('error', function (e) {
  console.log('Error: ', e);
});
```

[More information in the official documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html)

---

In your code, it will be inside `MongoCliente.connect` callback:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var app = express();

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;

// Initialize connection once
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_test", function(err, database) {
  if(err) throw err;

  db = database;

  // Start the application after the database connection is ready
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");

  db.on('close', function () {
    console.log('Conection closed');
  });

  db.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('Error: ', e);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could you explain more about the process after receiving an event? How should I write my router set to response immediately by this event?